# Use settings from config files for `UseUrl(...)`?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an Asp.net core application with the following code.

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
            ......
```

I don't want to hard code the port number 5000. How to read it from the configure file?

The startup.cs uses the config file for some settings. Should the code be duplicated in the program.cs? But how to get `IHostingEnvironment env`?

**Startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: See article [How to configure Kestrel URLs in ASP.NET Core](http://benfoster.io/blog/how-to-configure-kestrel-urls-in-aspnet-core-rc2)

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to create instance of `IConfiguration` in main method and use it for host configuration. Moreover you can directly use:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    //.AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
                    //.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    //.AddCommandLine(args)
                    //.AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseUrls(<values from config>);
}
```

Moreover, you can directly use `.UseConfiguration(config)` extension method:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
```

in this case, you configuration file should have 'server.urls' parameter. For your case:

```
"server.urls": "http://*:5000"
```

---

Also note, that when you run app directly, you can pass port from command line:

```
dotnet run --server.urls=http://0.0.0.0:5001
```

Comment: Just wonder, why it's so difficult to change the port number? Is there any existing configure file to use? I read one about launchSettings.json?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 actually "server.urls" config parameter allows to modify this quickly. I have updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. How about enable SSL? I'm running it using `dotnet myapp.dll`.

Comment: use KestrelServerOptions.UseHttps(). Example:  https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/samples/SampleApp/Startup.cs#L37-L43

Comment: I added file `hosting.json` with `"server.url": "http://*:5001"`, and added lines `var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()....` and `var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseConfiguration(config)` but it still listens on port 5000.

Comment: show your code.  I suggest even ask as a new question...
have you added .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", ...) ? have you added "hosting.json" into publishOptions in project.json?

Comment: I've created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581010/configurable-port-number-when-using-kestrel

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 also updated answer showing how to use command line to specify port

Comment: Great. Does it mean I even don't need the file `hosting.json`?

Comment: yes, as json is just one of the option how to pass "server.url"

Answer (score 5):

Reading config value as mentioned by @Set above but using it in `CreateHostBuilder()` works for WebHost.

```
private static string GetHostPort()
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile(SelfHostSettings, optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
        .Build();

    return config["HostPort"] ?? "8080";
}

private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var hostPort = GetHostPort();

    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(GetConfig)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseUrls($"http://localhost:{hostPort}");
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .UseWindowsService();
}
```

Note that trying to read config from `Main()` defaults the directory to `%windir%\system32` but calling the same from `CreateHostBuilder()` is set to application directory.

Comment: Is there a way in the `GetHostPort()` method to determine whether we're in development environment? i.e. get access to something like `env.IsDevelopment()`?

Answer (score 2):

Overriding Urls (listen on port 5020):

```sh
$ dotnet run --urls=http://*:5020
```

http/https:

```sh
$ dotnet run --urls="http://*:5020;https://*:5021"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set urls via Kestrel options like this:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(hostBuilder =>
    {
        hostBuilder.UseKestrel((builderContext, kestrelOptions) =>
        {
            kestrelOptions.ListenAnyIP(builderContext.Configuration.GetValue<int>("Port"));
        });
    }
);
```

As you can see, you can access the configuration via builder context and get any information from there. Including port.