# Configurable port number when using Kestrel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have done the following but it still doesn't work. Running `dotnet myapp.dll` still shows it's listening http://localhost:5000.

1. Create **hosting.json**

Code:

```
{
  "server.url": "http://*:5001"
}
```

2. Updated **Program.cs**

Code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(config) // added
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            //.UseUrls("http://*:5001")
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

3. Updated **project.json**

Code:

```
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config",
      "NLog.config",
      "hosting.json"
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to change order: `.SetBasePath` should be called before file reading

   ```
   var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
       .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
       .Build();
   ```
2. Use  `server.urls`, not  `server.url`

Comment: It still shows listening 5000 after the order is changed. I will update the question.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 also you have misprint. Use  "server.urls", not  "server.url"